# Quick Synthetic Division question

Tags: polynomials

> **Question:** How would you do synthetic division with $i$ where $i=\sqrt {-1}$?

Synthetic division is pretty straightforward: write down the coefficients of the $x$ terms, do some multiplication and addition, then see what is left!

But how would you use multiplication with $i$? More specifically, *how* would you do it? I have provided an example below:

> - Determine whether $x+i$ is a factor of $g(x)=3x^3-7x^2-8x+2$ by using Synthetic Division.

Comment: The same way as if you were dividing by $x-a$ where the number in your synthetic division would be $a$. If it divides, remainder should be zero. Note that $x=-i$ is a factor, so is $x=i$ and thus with regular long division, one can check if $x^2+1$ is a factor of your polynomial, which isn't the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x+i$ is a factor of your polynomial, then $-i$ would be a root. Check that $$\begin{align}3(-i)^3 - 7(-i)^2 +8i+2 &= 3i +7+8i+2 \\&= 9+11i \\&\ne 0\end{align}$$ thus $x+i$ is not a factor of $3x^3 - 7x^2 - 8x +2$.

Using Synthetic Division :

$$(3x^3 -7x^2 - 8x +2) -3x^2(x+i) = -(7+3i)x^2 -8x +2$$
then

$$\begin{align} (-(7+3i)x^2 -8x +2) + (7+3i)x(x+i) &= -(8-7i+3)x + 2\\&= -(11-7i)x+2
\end{align}$$

and finally

$$-(11-7i)x +2 +(11-7i)(x+i) = 9+11i$$

Furthermore, $$3x^3 -7x^2 - 8x +2=(x+i)(3x^2-(7+3i)x - (11-7i)) + 9+11i$$

Comment: How would you do that with *Synthetic Division*?

Comment: @Frank I edited